# Give a user access to a mounted device under another user

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, filesystems, minecraft

So I have a dual boot system that has both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 on separate on hard drives. I am trying to create a single Minecraft server following these instructions:

[How to Make Minecraft Server on Ubuntu 20.04 | Linuxize](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-make-minecraft-server-on-ubuntu-20-04/)

What I have done differently is on the Windows side I have copied all the folders and files that the server executable needs in order to run onto a USB. The folder where the executable is (on the actual hard drive containing Windows) has symbolic links to all the files/folders on the USB. This worked completely fine and the server ran without error. Now I am trying to do the same thing with Linux however, the instructions I posted above involved creating another user account, this account has the server executable and the same setup where I just created symbolic links to all the files/folders the executable needs. However, since the USB is mounted under the user I am logged in under (media /my user>/USB name), the user "minecraft" cannot read or write to these directories. I would like the user to gain access to this mounted device with read and write permissions but only to this device and no other mounted devices under my current user. How can I go about doing this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Something like this should work? https://askubuntu.com/questions/251206/mount-usb-drive-with-write-permissions-for-everyone-or-specific-user

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `/etc/fstab` entry like this:

```
UUID=0076... /mnt/minecraft  vfat  uid=minecraft,dmask=700,fmask=600,nofail  1  2
```

and run `mkdir --mode=000 /mnt/minecraft`. Use `blkid` for getting the UUID.